# Cisco AnyConnect rewrites the modified profile file

Tags: ubuntu, wsl2, cisco-anyconnect

I have installed `Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client (version 4.10.07073)` on WSL2/Windows 10 and am trying to connect, I get this error:

```
>> error: VPN establishment capability for a remote user is disabled.  A VPN connection will not be established.
>> state: Disconnected
```

I searched the Internet for information and found out that in the profile file `AnyConnect-Client-Profile.xml` you need to replace `<LinuxVPNEstablishment>LocalUsersOnly</LinuxVPNEstablishment>` with `<LinuxVPNEstablishment>AllowRemoteUsers</LinuxVPNEstablishment>`

I did it. But the next time you try to connect, the configuration file `AnyConnect-Client-Profile.xml` changes the changed value back to `LocalUsersOnly` value. Why and what should I do?